# Upgrading Ubuntu

Tags: upgrade

I required upgrade 15.04 to 16.04 but with this message: "An upgrade from 'vivid' to 'xenial' is not supported with this tool",  something is wrong. Please need yuor help.

Thanks

Oscar

Comment: How exactly did you attempt to do the upgrade?

Comment: Hi, please edit your question to include information on how you are trying to upgrade?